# Mismatched images in table cells with Picasso Library

Tags: java, android, picasso

I'm trying to fix an issues that I've seen previously and fixed on iOS, but am unable to fix on android. In iOS, I used the [SDWebImage library](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) to download and cache images. However, when scrolling through a long list of cells, the images would come up in the wrong cells. I was able ot fix this by doing the following:

```
@property (weak) id <SDWebImageOperation> imageOperation;

...

- (void)setFriend:(TAGUser *)friend {
...
    self.imageOperation = [[SDWebImageManager sharedManager] downloadWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:friend.profileImageUrl] options:SDWebImageRetryFailed
                                                                                progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize) {

                                                                                } completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished) {

                                                                                    if(!error) {
                                                                                        self.profileImageView.image = image;
                                                                                    }
                                                                                }];
...
}

- (void)prepareForReuse {

    [super prepareForReuse];

    if (self.imageOperation) {
        [self.imageOperation cancel];
    }

    self.imageOperation = nil;
}
```

On Android, I am using the [Picaso Libray](https://github.com/square/picasso) and trying to achieve the same result like so:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    if (vi == null) {
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.friend_row, parent, false);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.friendImage = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.friend_image);
     }

     final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag(); //Bad naming convention in my project I know, but it's a built-in method

     //THIS SHOULD IN THEORY CANCEL THE REQUEST OF THE OLD FRIEND URL
     Picasso.with(mActivity.getBaseContext()).cancelRequest(holder.friendImage);

     holder.friendImage.setImageDrawable(mActivity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.background_circle));

     final TagUser user = (TagUser) getItem(position);

     Picasso.with(mActivity.getBaseContext()).load(user.getProfileUrl()).transform(new RoundedTransformation(ViewUtility.convertPxToDp(mActivity, 23), 0)).fit().into(holder.friendImage,
                            new Callback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess() {
                                    holder.friendInitials.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onError() {
                                    holder.friendInitials.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                }
                            });
}
```

Even with `cancelRequeset` getting called, the profile images are still getting mismatched. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to call `cancel`. Picasso automatically sees when views are being re-used and will cancel old downloads for that image view.

I would also recommend using Picasso's `.placeholder` API for the background circle.

You seem to be missing a call to `setTag` when the layout is inflated. Hopefully that's just an error in copying to the post.

Lastly, create the `RoundedTransformation` once and re-use the same instance for all calls to Picasso.

In the end your code should look like this:

```
private final Transformation roundTransform;
// Set the following in constructor:
// roundTransform = new RoundedTransformation(ViewUtility.convertPxToDp(mActivity, 23), 0)

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    if (vi == null) {
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.friend_row, parent, false);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        vi.setTag(holder)
        holder.friendImage = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.friend_image);
     }

     final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag(); //Bad naming convention in my project I know, but it's a built-in method
     final TagUser user = (TagUser) getItem(position);

     Picasso.with(mActivity)
         .load(user.getProfileUrl())
         .placeholder(R.drawable.background_circle)
         .transform(roundTransform)
         .fit()
         .into(holder.friendImage,
              new Callback() {
                  @Override
                  public void onSuccess() {
                      holder.friendInitials.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                  }

                  @Override
                  public void onError() {
                      holder.friendInitials.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                  }
              });
}
```

Comment: turns out another AsyncTask was causing the mismatched images. I used this code though and was seeing the same issue until I manually called on cancel at the recycling of every view and then the issue was resolved. If you can edit your answer to reflect that I'll accept it.

Answer (score -1):

I would advice to use Volley by Google. I have used it in many projects and it never gave mismatched results even in case I had nearly 1000 images in 3 column gridView. [Volley](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley)